# error C4700: uninitialized local variable " " used

Tags: c, static

I know this question is everywhere, but i cannot find a solution, and at this point i got pretty frustrated. 
What I am trying to do is to create and use a static library. Got in the last point where i need to Build the solution, but i keep getting this error. I know the code has something, maybe more, MAYBE IS COMPLETE NONSENSE, but I can`t really see it after hours and hours trying to make it work. You know, "You cant see the forest because of the trees" W/e. Here are some screens.

[image]

[image]

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "matrice.h"

void din_alocation(int n, int m){
    float **mat;
    mat = (float**)calloc(n, sizeof(float*));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        mat[i] = (float*)calloc(m, sizeof(float));
}
void read(float **mat, int n, int m){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
        printf("mat[%d][%d]= ", i, j); scanf_s("%f", &mat[i][j]);
    }
}
void write(float **mat, int n, int m){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        printf("\n");
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            printf("%.2f  ", mat[i][j]);
    }
}

void din_realocation(float **mat, int n){
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        free(mat[i]);
    free(mat);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error should be pretty clear. You don't initialize the variable `mat` anywhere in the `main` function.

One solution is for the `din_alocation` function to return the data it allocates, and then do

```
mat = din_alocation(x, y);
```

Comment: Dont that in the past, but i keep getting those 2 errors:
LNK1120: 1 unresolved external  (file is test.exe)
Error 1 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "float * * __cdecl din_alocation(int &,int &)" (?din_alocation@@YAPAPAMAAH0@Z) referenced in function _main
(file is test.obj)

Comment: Yea, sorry, kept clicking enter instead of shift+enter.

Comment: @sNow11 And you have changed the definition (implementation) of the function to actually return a `float **`?

Comment: Yea. This is how the function looks in implementation: float** din_alocation(int n, int m) and at the end it returns mat.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Fixed it. (I modified the program by mistake after that)